# Adding a small description under Project name - waving portfolio

Tags: portfolio, field-description

I would like to add a small description, that appears before clicking on the picture under the project name.

I guess I need to edit the plug in but I don't know what to do exactly. I am thinking of writing the text I want in the description or caption of my picture.

Thank you :)

https://wordpress.org/plugins/waving-portfolio/